# I am getting an error when I try to connect oracle 10g with netbeans7.2 via the service window

Tags: java, oracle10g

I get an error:-

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl using oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection)

Please help me.
And guide me what to do as I need to use it in my web project.

Comment: Are you sure your DB server is running?

Comment: Or if they are running/ are they accessible?

Comment: I don't know how to check the DB server. Please explain how to check as all I know my isqlplus is running.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following solutions

```
1. If the network port is not open, or it is blocked by a firewall, you can try TELNET.
2. If DB listener is not running or is binding to a different network interface, you can try either TELNET or else use Oracle client tools to connect.
3. If again the problem persists, you may please start the listener through command prompt (lsnrctl start)
```